# Creating objects from a class with unique names in Python3

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a an Enemy class, so my first object is:

```
enemy1 = Enemy()
```

Now I need to make a lot of enemies with names like this:

```
enemy1 = Enemy()
enemy2 = Enemy()
enemy3 = Enemy()
enemy4 = Enemy()
```

How can I make a loop that basically does this:

```
for i in range(1, 5)
    enemy + i = Enemy()
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `globals()` function to get the dictionary of global namepsace, and then create your variables using string.

Example -

```
In [19]: class Enemy:
   ....:        pass
   ....:

In [20]: gbl = globals()

In [21]: for i in range(1,6):
   ....:     gbl['enemy' + str(i)] = Enemy()
   ....:

In [22]: enemy1
Out[22]: <__main__.Enemy at 0x4903a58>

In [23]: enemy2
Out[23]: <__main__.Enemy at 0x4903a90>

In [24]: enemy3
Out[24]: <__main__.Enemy at 0x4903b00>

In [25]: enemy4
Out[25]: <__main__.Enemy at 0x4903b70>

In [26]: enemy5
Out[26]: <__main__.Enemy at 0x4903be0>
```

Comment: Beautiful answer but is there any alternate way to do so

Comment: You can also do `exec`, example - `exec('enemy' + str(7) + ' = Enemy()')` . But that is dangerous, and you should avoid it, best would be using the `globals`